# Typescript prepended union template literal types

Tags: typescript

I there a way to create literal string types from other string types with a prefix? Beter knowing there isn't than dwendle on this idea.

```js
type UserField = "id" | "name";
type PostField = "id" | "message" | ("author." + UserField); // Something like this?
let somePostFields: PostField[] = ["id", "message", "author.name"];
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgMQJYQDYBMoF4oBEqWBUAPoQHYCGAthAQNwBQokUACgPZzBqY58REuUL04cagHMGogAbUArsAAWXRADoAJAG94SftgC+clhgjAocLvW69DWOAC5OPPumwBtALp4on4QIAGjEICWkGEIVlNU0aejlvRiA)

Comment: @VLAZ Unsure how this doc just escaped my searches. This does answer my question, so if you answer this one i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the feature template literal types using string interpolation allowing union types to combine.

```
type UserField = "id" | "name";
type PostField = "id" | "message" | `author.${UserField}`;
```